# Unable to remove user Glance

Tags: ubuntu

Installed and removed glance but the user glance is listing at the time of login. How can I remove user glance?

Already tried sudo apt remove glance
glance is removed but not the user.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `sudo deluser glance`?

If there is a home directory as well, use `sudo deluser --remove-home glance`

You can find more info about it [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-and-delete-users-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Already tried but no avail.

Comment: Thanks jzegers for the support. Tried "sudo deluser glance" but nothing happened. Haven't tried "sudo deluser --remove-home glance". However, the issue is resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

At first, Clicked Activities and searched for users. There I've got all the users then selected user glance and clicked delete, the user is deleted.